# Обращение к компьютеру при реализации p2p сети

Tags: nat, p2p

Пишу p2p мессенджер и возникла проблема с обращение к компьютеру пользователя напрямую без серверов, то есть как обойти блокировки Nat провайдера, роутера, когда просто запрос приходит из вне и не какой сессии на стороне провайдера нету. Знаю что существует мессенджер Tox, который является p2p и там как то это реализовано.

Comment: Если два клиент, и оба сокрыты за nat-провайдера (серый ip), то прямое соединение между ними не возможно. Если хоть у одного белый ip, то нужно будет всегда вешаться на его порт. В таком случае обладателю белого ip сложно будет инициировать соединение: серый должен будет постоянно коннетится к белому и проверять: "не хочет ли белый с ним поговорить?".

Comment: В общем если два серых ip, то соединение  без промежуточного хоста ( с белым ip) невозможно. Я думаю, что если в твоей сети будет 10 серых и хотя бы 1 белый, то все они могут использовать порт белого для обмена. Если появятся 2 белых, то нагрузка будет делиться между ними... Какой-никакой сервер все же нужен, хотя бы для того, чтобы узнавать, к кому же прицепиться... По другому никак

Comment: В  думаю в торренте не все раздающие обладают белыми IP, но все же они раздают. Раздают через чужие порты, до которых могут дотянуться, раздают тебе, через твой же белый порт. ( если он у тебя белый)

Comment: у меня пока есть мысль сделать возможность каждого пользователя стать промежуточным хостом, но вы не подскажите есть ли возможность  как то программно определить динамический у пользователя ip или статический!?

Comment: возможно вы путаете пары понятий статический/динамический и серый/белый. На случай если путаете: белый/серый определяет сокрыты ли  вы  за NAT - провайдера. Динамический/статический определяет постоянен ли ваш IP адрес или же он может меняться при переподлкючении

Comment: динамический ip - адрес вполне может быть белым. Т.е можно с такого адреса открыть порт и подрубаться к нему. Проблема тут в том, что адрес будет постоянно меняться и не ясно, куда подключаться.
На счет программного определения: динамический или статический программно не определить. Это иногда даже эмпирически сложно будет выяснить. Верный способ - узнать у провайдера.

Comment: Белый или серый сложно, но возможно определить, хотя наверно не всегда. Знаете о команде tracert?  Она выдает последовательность узлов, которую проходит ваш ip пакет, чтобы дотянуться до определенного хоста. Последовательность действий примерно такая: проверяете свой внешний ip на каком - нибудь специальном сервисе, далее делаете tracert: первым будет локальный ip компа, второй локальный ip вашего роутера, а вот третий, если белый, то будет совпадать с ip, который показал вам специальный сервис, а если серый, то будет какой-нибудь другой адрес (ваш локальный ip в сети провайдера)

Comment: Нужно помнить, что иногда роутера может и не быть и ПК напрямую может смотреть в инет, хотя это сейчас редкость.  Мне кажется более простой способ все таки иметь внешний сервис с белый статическим ip: вы  ему сообщаете, что хотите чтобы он тестировал, а сами в это время открывайте порт

Comment: спасибо огромное.всё очень доступно объяснили!